# Product package with quantity 0 continues to appear in the cart

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5-p2

Guys I need help with something in magento, I look everywhere and I couldn't solve it and since I'm a novice I decided to resort to you. On the page of bundle products when setting the input of a product to 0 and clicking on buy it continues to appear in the cart. How can I solve this? I need to resolve this and I need help.

[image]

[image]